# Getting "Bad file descriptor" error during tar

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to tar a dir with this command "tar -cpSWf myfile.tar workdir; gzip myfile.tar", but I get this error for some of the files in workdir dir.

```
 tar: my/sub/dir/file1.oa: Cannot seek to 1536: Bad file descriptor
```

I run the same command on other dir and there's no such error.  Is it because the .oa files are corrupted, or the disk is failing?  Is this a common issue when using tar?  Is there any way to repair this error?

Comment: That's probably the detection of sparseness that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Questions

> Is it because the .oa files are corrupted, or the disk is failing? Is this a common issue when using tar? Is there any way to repair this error?

It isn't really relevant whether this issue is typical or not (I've not encountered it before), I'd start by attempting to `tar` up a single file and see if can't isolate the issue a bit more, and also repeat it.

```
$ tar -cpSWf somefile.tar my/sub/dir/file1.oa
```

Also as an aside, you can save yourself a step and tar and compress all at once:

```
$ tar zcpSWf somefile.tar.gz ...
```

I would also look to take out the `SW` switches temporarily to see if that has any impact on your ability to `tar` these problematic files too.

If these errors are a warning that there are bad sectors on the HDD you might need to run an `fsck` or use a tool such as [HDAT2](http://www.hdat2.com/) to attempt to repair any damaged sectors. This repair work may still leave the `.oa` file in a corrupted state, however.

Comment: Thanks slm.  If I remove "SW", there is no error.

I also find that by copying the workdir to another partition on the disk and run tar with the same "-cpSWf" option, the command works without any error.